# Salt-key command in runner

Tags: python, module, salt-stack

I'm writing a custom Salt Stack runner to wrap accepting and rejecting minions. How do I call salt-key from my python runner that's equivalent to this from command line

`salt-key -a {minion_name}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't provide you a definite answer, but here are my two cents:

The source code of the salt-key script is [this one](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/scripts/salt-key). Following the call chain, I reached [this module](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/01490387d714256191b3017fe488175b55231bbf/salt/key.py) which contains several classes to do key processing.

The module's documentation reads:

> The Salt Key backend API and interface used by the CLI. The Key class can be
>   used to **manage salt keys directly without interfacing with the CLI**.

This is the [mentioned class](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/01490387d714256191b3017fe488175b55231bbf/salt/key.py#L502).

Based on [this code](https://doc.wikimedia.org/puppetsource/modules/openstack/files/monitor_labs_salt_keys.py), I presume it's used like:

```
import salt.client
import salt.key

client = salt.client.LocalClient()
key_manager = salt.key.Key(client.opts)
key_manager.accept('web*')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this question is answered, I would like to add my two cents on this subject.

In order to do key interactions programmatically, we use Wheel in salt. Usage is rather simple and clear:

```
from salt import config
from salt import wheel
masterOpts = config.master_config('/etc/salt/master')
wheelClient = wheel.WheelClient(masterOpts)
wheelClient.cmd('key.accept', ['minionId1'])
```

Bunch of other operations could be found in [SaltStack documentatation here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/wheel/all/salt.wheel.key.htmlhttp://)